reordering question about __ATOMIC_RELAXED with if statement
int flag = 0;

int threadA()
{
    if(__atomic_load_n(&flag, __ATOMIC_RELAXED))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // do something A

    return 0;
}

int threadB()
{
    __atomic_store_n(&flag, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);

    // do something B

    __atomic_store_n(&flag, 0, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}

threadB() executes // do something B and I don't want to execute threadA() when threadB() do something..
I have a question about __ATOMIC_RELAXED with if statement. Is it possible that // do something A is executed before if statement in threadA()? Because of __ATOMIC_RELAXED, it does not prevent reordering.
I think that reordering does not happen because if statement make this code run differently. But I'm not sure. I'm beginner of multi-threaded programming, so I want to clarify my understanding.

This code uses GNU C __atomic builtins.  C stdatomic and C++ std::atomic functions can be implemented as simple wrappers for these builtins operations of similar names.  Note that the GNU C functions do atomic operations on plain int or other types, not needing _Atomic int or std::atomic<int>.

What if, while A is in the middle of // do something A, thread B enters // do something B?

Speculative execution can continue past the if and later confirm that branch prediction went the same way after things in your attempt at a critical section have already loaded and/or stored shared state. Mutual exclusion (locking) needs acquire and release (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/), and an atomic RMW for taking the lock like exchange, test_and_set, or compare_exchange. (Or you need seq_cst for Dekker's or Peterson's algorithms, which are slower and clunkier but work with only loads and stores)

Do you really only need one-way mutual exclusion?  What if threadA gets past the if then blocks for a long time (e.g. because the system is busy and that page of code got paged out to disk).  Then it can resume executing later, potentially right after threadB set the flag.  Is that somehow ruled out by not starting the threadA work until threadB has already set the flag?

So anyway, yes, runtime reordering around that if is very possible with RELAXED instead of ACQUIRE.  Separate from that, your whole algorithm appears very flawed for what you say you're wanting to do, and would be broken even with SEQ_CST.

@HolyBlackCat It should make some problems. I should fix that problem...

@PeterCordes I understand. What I want to do is that executing threadA while threadB is not running and vice versa. It needs mutual exclusion.  I should study it more.. Thanks for your explanation and a post.

Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly shows x86 asm.  Should be easy to translate to C: the exchange needs to be acquire, the store in unlock needs to be release.

Protection from race conditions and protection from instruction re-ordering are generally two different things. If your protection against race conditions is atomic access, then that in itself says nothing about re-ordering. Whereas mutex, critical section etc by their nature have to also act as memory barriers, since the code they are protection must never be re-ordered outside the mutex lock/critical section.
